# Custom header "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Tags: ios, swift, header, collectionview

Here is my override  function for UICollectionUICollectionViewControllerView

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        var view =  UICollectionReusableView()
        if kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader {
            let viewHeader : Header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind, withReuseIdentifier: "header", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Header
            if let userName = viewHeader.userName {
                userName.text = "James Bond"
            }

            view = viewHeader
        }

        return view

    }
```

The problem is whenever I tried to run the app, following the debugging it always popup error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" in the line

```
let viewHeader : Header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind, withReuseIdentifier: "header", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Header
```

Below is  my viewDidLoad override

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
self.collectionView!.delegate = self
collectionView!.dataSource = self

collectionView!.registerClass(SquareCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
collectionView!.registerClass(Header.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "header")  // UICollectionReusableView
layout.headerReferenceSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width, 200)

let cellNib = UINib(nibName: "SquareCell", bundle: nil)
collectionView!.registerNib(cellNib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")

let headerlNib = UINib(nibName: "HeaderView", bundle: nil)
collectionView!.registerNib(headerlNib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "header")


self.view.addSubview(collectionView!)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that in my Header.swift class I accidentally add non-existing image name

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.cover.image = UIImage(named: "cover")
        self.userName.text = "Jame Bond"
    }
```

so I deleted the image name and all back to normal :)